# Create NSManagedObject Subclass... make a new Error in my project

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode10

i want to add a class for my entity by Editor\Create NSManagedObject Subclass... menu . but when i added it , the project made an error , this is the message:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/mohsenkhodadadzadeh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/walk-fcnteanemrfigmfaalqkvwigvwqc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/walk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/walk.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WalkEntity+CoreDataProperties.o':
1) Target 'walk' (project 'walk') has compile command for Swift source files
2) Target 'walk' (project 'walk') has compile command for Swift source files


Multiple commands produce '/Users/mohsenkhodadadzadeh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/walk-fcnteanemrfigmfaalqkvwigvwqc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/walk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/walk.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WalkEntity+CoreDataClass.o':
1) Target 'walk' (project 'walk') has compile command for Swift source files
2) Target 'walk' (project 'walk') has compile command for Swift source files
```

i changed that build system to Legacy Build system in  File->Project settings . but it diden't work yet

this project made with xcode9 and i develope it with xcode 10 now

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Select the `xcdatamodeld` file in the project navigator, select the entity and press <kbd>⌥⌘3</kbd> – in Xcode 13 <kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd> – to show the Data Model Inspector.

If you created the class manually the `Codegen` popup must be set to `Manual/None` otherwise the class file is created implicitly.

Comment: I also had to clean build folders and relaunch xcode in order for it to recognize my new manually created class.

Comment: Seems unfair that I can only upvote once on this answer . Thanks

Comment: After cleaning, I had to build it first before running it in order to work. Clean is Shift + Command + K and build is Shift + Command + B. Thanks Apple ;)

Comment: Works for me, but with some manipulations. If you created files with Class codegen, delete them, set Manual codegen and clean project then build. After this steps all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 11**

1.Remove info list from `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`

2.Remove Created Subclass from `Build Phases > Compile Sources`

Than Run if its not working use **legacy build settings**

From: `File > Project Settings > build settings > legacy build settings`

[image]