# I am getting Xcode build errors as soon as I insert NSManagedObject in Swift4.2 on Xcode 10.2

Tags: swift, xcode, nsmanagedobject

Every time I add NSManagedObject subclass to a vanilla app (with CoreData enabled) or to a vanilla app without CoreData enabled at the start but added after, Xcode (10.2.1) / Swift (4.2) is throwing up 3 errors.

I'm trying to create a simple application in Xcode v10.2 (have just updated to 10.2.1) that uses Core Data.  I have tried to do this by two methods ie. starting a brand new app and ensuring Core Data is ticked, and also starting a vanilla app without Core Data ticked and then adding Core Data.  The issue I'm having is occurring after I create an entity and some entity attributes (everything compiles fine up to that point every time), however the issue occurs as soon as I go to add NSManagedObject subclass from the Editor dropdown.

As soon as I've added NSManagedObject, Xcode reindexes and I get 3 errors, two stating that "Multiple commands produce...." and another one that states Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code.

I've tried to recreate the NSManagedObject, however that makes no difference.  I have followed the instructions to add a build statement (SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE set to NO), but it makes no difference.

I'm not trying to do anything fancy here, just get to a point where I have NSManagedObject subclass enabled as part of CoreData so that I can get on and write the rest of my app on Xcode 10.2/Swift 4.2.

Also I have just updated to Xcode 10.2.1 which has made no difference ie. problem still occurs when you try and add the NSManagedObject subclass.

Any ideas anyone?

[Screen shot of compiler errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoTsG.png)

Comment: You don't say what the multiple commands are producing but see if the 2nd answer here is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for the links.  The 3rd answer helps in that it hides 2 of the errors if I set the compilation to legacy, however, I don't really want to do that as it is masking the real issue (which looks like a bug in Xcode to me).

Comment: Woohoo - I've found the answer !!!  The key is searching for the error on stack overflow for 'Build fails with "Command failed with a nonzero exit code" ' and within those answers there is a post from JeffreyWang23 on Sep16'18 that fixes this.  Am trying to include the link but I just followed that advice to delete the Entity+CoreDataClass.swift and Entity+CoreDataProperties.swift from within Xcode, then under "class" of the entity model inspector, change "module" to Current Product Module and "codegen" to Manual/None, then recreate NSManagedObject.  All the errors then disappeared ! :) :) :)

Comment: Link to resolution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357296/11407686 (All credit to the authors of the other article). :)

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer !!! The key is searching for the error on stack overflow for 'Build fails with "Command failed with a nonzero exit code" ' and within those answers there is a post from JeffreyWang23 on Sep16'18 that fixes this.

Link to resolution: [stackoverflow.com/a/52357296/11407686](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52357296/11407686) (All credit to the authors of the other article).

I just followed that advice to delete the `Entity+CoreDataClass.swift` and `Entity+CoreDataProperties.swift` from within Xcode, then under "class" of the entity model inspector, change `"module"` to `Current Product Module` and `"codegen"` to `Manual/None`, then recreate `NSManagedObject`.

All the errors then disappeared ! :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

for solve this issue you should Select the xcdatamodeld file in the project navigator, select the entity and press ⌥⌘3 (Data Model Inspector).

If you created the class manually the Codegen popup must be set to Manual/None otherwise the class file is created implicitly.

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105066/3992606)

[image]